# Can't require csv lib in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to use some library, that can work with csv format. I've found [this](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv)

But I have a problem with it's require.
I do

```
npm install csv
```

then do require

```
csv = require('csv');
```

When I run my project, I get in terminal follow error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.exports.inherits (util.js:538:43)
    at Object. (/.../node_modules/csv/node_modules/csv-generate/lib/index.js:122:6)*

Who does know, what problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My be you're not following the right documentation for the right version of csv module. this is the new [website of csv module](http://csv.adaltas.com/)